# Scrapy CrawlSpider - Extract Links from data attributes (LinkExtractor rule)

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm having trouble getting LinkExtractor to find links in data-attributes.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<a href='#' data-url='/path/to/page' >
```

The LinkExtractor is this:

```
LinkExtractor(allow=('us/support/', ),attrs=('href','data-href','data-url',))
```

Other links exist on the page with urls in the HREFs, and the LinkExtractor finds those fine, just not the data-attributes.

I've found similar questions about finding tags based on data attributes, but none about using the data-attribute value in the LinkExtractor.

I would think this is pretty common, so I'm surprised at the trouble I'm having to find the answer.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: That should work. You'll need to share your code and/or url if you need help figuring out why it's not working in your case.

Comment: Thanks Stranac, it does work.  My problem was that I didn't have follow=True, and those links were on a secondary page.  The other links on the page are a header and footer, which were ignored because they're duplicates, so it didn't register with me that it wasn't following any links on the second page, so I thought it was a problem with the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are setting the allow argument, which is limiting the `LinkExtractor` to only go and look for those matching links, you setting the `attrs` argument is correct, just remove the `allow`:

```
le = LinkExtractor(attrs=('href','data-href','data-url',))
```

Comment: I appreciate the advice, but it's behaving as expected.  The problem was that I needed to add follow=true.  The links in the data attributes are on a secondary page, so it didn't even search for links to follow.  All good now.